# Nuxt, transitions not working for child routes (displayed using NuxtChild)

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, transition, router

I'm having trouble getting transitions to work for my child routes.

I have the following pages:

```
pages/
  child/
    _id.vue
  child.vue
  index.vue
```

Navigating between index and any of the child routes triggers transitions, but when navigating from one child route to another child route there is no transition.

Note that there is a static route **/child** and dynamic routes for **/child/_id**. The `<nuxt-child />` component is inside child.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">
      Child Root Page
    </h1>
    <nuxt-child />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  key(route) {
    return route.fullPath
  },
}
</script>
```

If I remove the static route **child.vue** and move `<nuxt-child />` to index.vue all transitions work, but then I don't have the 'parent' child page anymore.

Is it possible to get the transitions to work in this case?

I have a [small repo](https://github.com/metervara/nuxt-child-transition) showing the problem and a [github page](https://metervara.github.io/nuxt-child-transition/) with the site deployed.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Yes, I am encountering a similar issue. Anyone find a solution?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution to this yet :-(