# Transitions not working on nuxt-child component when route changes

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-transitions

I want to create a very simple nuxt transition between child routes.

The structure is:

```
index.vue

index

--one.vue

--two.vue

--three.vue
```

index.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-link to="/one">one</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="/two">two</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="/three">three</nuxt-link>

    <nuxt-child :key="$route.fullPath"></nuxt-child>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  transition: 'fade',
  data(){
    return {

    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active{
    transition: all 1s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to{
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade-leave, .fade-enter-to{
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

The child components:

one.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        1
    </div>
</template>
```

two.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        2
    </div>
</template>
```

three.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        3
    </div>
</template>
```

**The problem is:**

that nothing happens! when I change routes, they change in a way like there is no transition.

**what I have done:**

I tried to do exactly what the nuxt document has said.

Also I searched a lot about it, but unfortunately, none of the similar questions have been answered.

[question1](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1737)

[question2](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4449)

[question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786780/nuxt-transitions-not-working-for-child-routes-displayed-using-nuxtchild)